# c++ abstract base class postfix operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have a question about implementing a shared iterator interface.

As common practice for postix operator the function might look like this:

```
IteratorClass operator ++(int) {
  IteratorClass temp = *this;

  //increment stuff

  return temp
}
```

And most of the time this is fine. In my case I am trying to implement 3 iterators for one class. Each iterator will load a local collection class with data but each derived iterator would load it in a different way. Because the collection class would be the same and all of the code for the operators( postfix/prefix ++/--, *) would be the same I thought a nice way to implement this would be inheritance:

```
struct iterator {
  protected:
  Collection collection;
  public:
  operator++(int);
  operator++;
  operator--(int);
  operator--;

  virtual load() = 0;

}

struct iterator1 : public iterator {
  virtual load() { custom load function }
}

struct iterator2 : public iterator {
  virtual load() { custom load function }
}
```

The problem are the postfix operators... They are trying to create an object of an abstract type and then returning it. Any suggestions for workarounds or structure changes?

Comment: Do you really need to have postfix operator as generally it is a bad idea to use them for iterators anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to make the base class aware of the final class. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct iterator_base {
  public:
  T operator++(int) {
    T temp = static_cast<T&>(*this);
    ++*this;
    return temp;
  }
  T& operator++() {
    // ++ mutation goes here
    return *this;
  }
  // ... likewise for --, etc.
};

struct iterator1: public iterator_base<iterator1> {
  // ... custom load function
};
```

This approach is called *static polymorphism*, and allows you (in some cases) to completely eschew `virtual` and therefore make your objects smaller. You can omit the `load` declaration from the base classes and call `T::load` as `static_cast<T&>(*this).load()`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip! I've tried implementing what you said and linked too and it's almost there but now im stuck on, well, the next error....


'AVLTree<_K,_T>::BinaryTreeTraversal<_D>' to 'AVLTree<_K,_T>::InOrder'

Do I need some kind of casting in here?

After doing:
struct InOrder : public Traversal<InOrder>

Comment: @kris What is the line of the error? Did you correctly declare `operator++(int)` and `operator++()` as returning `T` and `T&` respectively?

Comment: Here is the exact code, it fails on the second line.

_D operator ++ (int) {
_D temp = *this;
++local;
return temp;
}

Edit: This doesnt format nicely

Comment: @kris It's a good idea to use `++*this` in your post-increment operator, so that the increment logic is spelled-out only once. It's hard to say why your code doesn't compile without seeing more of the code - the example I posted does.

Comment: It's in Visual c++, maybe that's why... local is a different variable that i am hiding when im 'iterating.' The function is defined inline but i also tried to define it outside, same problem...

The error is as follows: Error 2 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'libsdk::AVLTree<_K,_T>::BinaryTreeTraversal<_D>' to 'libsdk::AVLTree<_K,_T>::InOrder'

Comment: @kris Then try adding an explicit `static_cast`, such as: `_D temp = static_cast<D&>(*this)`