# Pure virtual function in abstract class with return type of base/derived type

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual, abstract-base-class

I wish to make each derived class of a base class to implement a function (in this case the postfix operator) which has the derived class' type as return type, as this:

```cpp
class A {
    virtual A operator++(int) =0;
}

class B : public A {
    B operator++(int);
}
```

This generates errors of the kind `return type 'A' is an abstract class`. What to do? As far as I understand the postfix must return the actual type and not a reference/pointer to the type.

Comment: Opt for a pointer or reference, those don't require a complete type.

Comment: In the case of the postfix operator mustn't the return type be the class type without modifiers?

Comment: Casting for reopening, I suppose this is the right duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18172858/1938163

Answer (score 3):

What about using the [CRTP pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4173254/3093378):

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    virtual T operator++(int) =0;
};

class B : public A<B> {
    B operator++(int) override
    {
        // do something here
        return *this; 
    }
};
```

PS: just saw that @Marco A. posted a link with a similar approach. I will keep my answer for completeness, don't feel any pressure to vote it.

Comment: Amazing! Are there any downsides to this, like bloating generated code?

Comment: @VaradMahashabde Not that I'm aware of; I think it should be the same as the typical code bloat due to usage of virtual functions.